# eslint import/order merge pathGroups

Tags: javascript, import, eslint

This is the relevant part of  my `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
    "import/order": [
                    "error",
                    {
                        "pathGroups": [
                            {
                                "pattern": "@/**",
                                "group": "internal",
                                "position": "after"
                            }
                        ],
                        "groups": [
                            "builtin",
                            "external",
                            "internal",
                            "unknown",
                            "parent",
                            "sibling",
                            "index",
                            "object",
                            "type"
                        ],
                        "newlines-between": "always-and-inside-groups",
                        "alphabetize": {
                            "order": "asc"
                            "caseInsensitive": true
                        }
                    }
                ],
```

I wan't to ensure that eslint does not notice:
`There should be at least one empty line between import groups (eslint import/order)`

When the imports are like:

```
import { FeedbackService } from '@/shared/services/FeedbackService.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
```

For sake of simplicity i want to still allow `./direct-file.ts` instead of using the import alias because the import path can be way longer then.

Is that possible with this rule?

I tried the following to adjust my pathGroups like this:

```json
"pathGroups": [
    {
        "pattern": ["@/**", "./**"],
        "group": "internal",
        "position": "after"
    }
],
```

and like this

```json
"pathGroups": [
    {
        "pattern": "@/**",
        "group": "internal",
        "position": "after"
    },
    {
        "pattern": "./**,
        "group": "internal",
        "position": "after"
    }
],
```

But that does not resolve my problem. Is there a builtin solution available that i can't find in the docs: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/order.md

Comment: I would use stick to just one style: relative or absolute; not both.